# How do I turn on peaceful mode?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

The 0.7.0 update for Minecraft Pocket Edition just came out a half hour ago. But after I went through the options, I didn't find peaceful mode. So can somebody please tell me what happened to it and how to turn it off and on?

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, this has been changed to a slider with only two settings. You can see the slider in the Options menu, labeled "Difficulty":

[image]

Moving it all the way to the left turns on Peaceful mode. I confirmed this by going out in the dark, walking up to a skeleton, and then flipping the slider all the way to the left: the skeleton disappeared.

There's no visual feedback as to what difficulty setting the slider's two positions *are*, which is a UI fail on Mojang's part. But seeing as this is the first Alpha release with these new menus, it will probably improve.