# Minecraft abandoned village

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was just coming home from exploring (pe) and I stumbled upon anot abandoned village. Like it was covered in cobwebs and mossy cobblestone. Doors were gone and it was deserted, I couldn't find animals, zombies/ zombie villagers. It was a ghost town. Any information on what this is or if it's natural?[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of [Pocket Edition 0.15.0](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Village#History), Villages have a 5% chance to spawn as what is known as a Zombie Village. In this mode, Villages will spawn with moss stone and cobblestone as noted, and Zombie villagers will be present.

Your case of Zombie Villagers not spawning is likely a result of you either being in [Peaceful mode](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119428/how-do-i-turn-on-peaceful-mode), or just bad luck.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me,  I also went back and it was to the brim with zombies. At least 20. But thanks again!